# What is the Complexity of N-ary tree insertion and searching?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am implementing an N-1ry tree in C#. I am wondering how can I calculate the complexity of below methods. Here is my code:

Structure:

```
public class Node
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Node Children { get; set; }
    public Node Sibilings { get; set; }

}
```

This method for searching:

```
public Node search(Node root, int data)
{
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (data == root.Value)
        return root;

    Node t = search(root.Children, data);
    if (t == null)
        t = search(root.Sibilings, data);
    return t;
}
```

This method for insertion:

```
public void Add(int[] data)
{
    Node temp = null;
    temp = search(ROOT, data[0]);

    if (temp == null)
        temp = new Node(data[0]);

    if (this.ROOT == null)
        ROOT = temp;
    Node parent = temp;

    for (int j = 1; j <= this.NoOfChildrens; j++)
    {
        // for first child
        if (j == 1)
        {
            parent.Children = new Node(data[j]);
            parent = parent.Children;
        }
        //for all other childs
        else
        {
            parent.Sibilings = new Node(data[j]);
            parent = parent.Sibilings;
        }

    }

}
```

Program entry point:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    NAryTree naryTree = new NAryTree(3);

    // 1st element in each row is node Value,>=2nd....=>value of child

    int[][] data = { new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, new int[] { 2, 1, 6,0 }, new int[] { 3, 8, 9, 10 }, new int[] { 4, 0, 0, 0 } };

    naryTree.Add(data[0]);
    naryTree.Add(data[1]);
    naryTree.Add(data[2]);
    naryTree.Add(data[3]);
    naryTree.Add(new int[] {10,3,6,4});

    naryTree.preorder(naryTree.ROOT);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What is the bigO complexity of these methods?

Comment: You've shown only some code, but lack of code that re-balances children in `Add` method hints that O(total_number_of_nodes) is best option (could be much worse depending how bad other methods are). Balanced trees should get O(log n) for add/remove/search.

Comment: I can't understand this code. The search method should have at least one `for` in my opinion. Also I think a node shouldn't have access to its siblings.

Comment: I am just implement N-Ary tree and I update my Question

Comment: @QasimAhmed Does this code work?

Comment: Yes I am updating it

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 plz check now it is working code

Comment: in my view they are all equals to O(n) cause we have `if` and `for` statements. Consequently, it is necessary to iterate through each items as big O notation suppose of estimation the worst case.

Comment: @StepUp is recursion counts in bigO notaion ?

Comment: @QasimAhmed of course it does.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 if recursion matters ho we can say it is  O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what we have in `Search` method. It is not a binary tree and we have recursion. So the `Search` method will call `N` times till we find a necessary value. So we can conclude that we have O(N) where `N` is the maximum(worst) number of iteration to find a value at the last iteration:

```
public Node search(Node root, int data)
{
    if (root == null)
        return null;

    if (data == root.Value)
        return root;

    Node t = search(root.Children, data);
    if (t == null)
        t = search(root.Sibilings, data);
    return t;
}
```

For Addition method is simpler as we have `for` statement and no nested loops. So we have `O(N)` for `Addition` method.

[As Wisconsin university says:](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html)

> So for loops for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
>       sequence of statements } The loop executes N times, so the sequence of statements also executes N times. Since we assume the
>   statements are O(1), the total time for the for loop is N * O(1),
>   which is O(N) overall.